# Create a data frame in Python containing a combination of all values from three lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have two lists: `gender = ['Male', 'Female']` and `subject = ['Math3_Exam_Mark', 'Math6_Exam_Mark', 'Math9_Exam_Mark', 'ELA3_Exam_Mark', 'ELA6_Exam_Mark', 'ELA9_Exam_Mark']`, plus an ndarray `birthMonthYear` containing a list of dates extracted from a CSV file.

I'd like to create a new data frame with three columns: gender, subject, birthMonthYear. There should be rows for every combination of gender, subject and birthMonthYear.

Is there an easy way to do this, perhaps with pandas? I imagine I could create nested `foreach` loops that ran through each list to create the data frame, but if there is something simpler I'd like to try it.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Also, please add a sample/mock of birthMonthYear to make your example fully reproducible

Answer (score 1):

**Setup**

```
gender = ['Male', 'Female']
subject = ['Math3_Exam_Mark', 'Math6_Exam_Mark', 'Math9_Exam_Mark',
           'ELA3_Exam_Mark', 'ELA6_Exam_Mark', 'ELA9_Exam_Mark']
birthMonthYear = pd.date_range('2010-01-31', periods=2, freq='M')
```

**Option 1**
`itertools.product`

```
from itertools import product

pd.DataFrame(
    list(product(gender, subject, birthMonthYear)),
    columns=['Gender', 'Subject', 'BirthMonthYear']
)

    Gender          Subject BirthMonthYear
0     Male  Math3_Exam_Mark     2010-01-31
1     Male  Math3_Exam_Mark     2010-02-28
2     Male  Math6_Exam_Mark     2010-01-31
3     Male  Math6_Exam_Mark     2010-02-28
4     Male  Math9_Exam_Mark     2010-01-31
5     Male  Math9_Exam_Mark     2010-02-28
6     Male   ELA3_Exam_Mark     2010-01-31
7     Male   ELA3_Exam_Mark     2010-02-28
8     Male   ELA6_Exam_Mark     2010-01-31
9     Male   ELA6_Exam_Mark     2010-02-28
10    Male   ELA9_Exam_Mark     2010-01-31
11    Male   ELA9_Exam_Mark     2010-02-28
12  Female  Math3_Exam_Mark     2010-01-31
13  Female  Math3_Exam_Mark     2010-02-28
14  Female  Math6_Exam_Mark     2010-01-31
15  Female  Math6_Exam_Mark     2010-02-28
16  Female  Math9_Exam_Mark     2010-01-31
17  Female  Math9_Exam_Mark     2010-02-28
18  Female   ELA3_Exam_Mark     2010-01-31
19  Female   ELA3_Exam_Mark     2010-02-28
20  Female   ELA6_Exam_Mark     2010-01-31
21  Female   ELA6_Exam_Mark     2010-02-28
22  Female   ELA9_Exam_Mark     2010-01-31
23  Female   ELA9_Exam_Mark     2010-02-28
```

---

**Option 2**
`pd.MultiIndex.from_product`

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [gender, subject, birthMonthYear],
    names=['Gender', 'Subject', 'BirthMonthYear']
)

pd.DataFrame(index=idx).reset_index()

    Gender          Subject BirthMonthYear
0     Male  Math3_Exam_Mark     2010-01-31
1     Male  Math3_Exam_Mark     2010-02-28
2     Male  Math6_Exam_Mark     2010-01-31
3     Male  Math6_Exam_Mark     2010-02-28
4     Male  Math9_Exam_Mark     2010-01-31
5     Male  Math9_Exam_Mark     2010-02-28
6     Male   ELA3_Exam_Mark     2010-01-31
7     Male   ELA3_Exam_Mark     2010-02-28
8     Male   ELA6_Exam_Mark     2010-01-31
9     Male   ELA6_Exam_Mark     2010-02-28
10    Male   ELA9_Exam_Mark     2010-01-31
11    Male   ELA9_Exam_Mark     2010-02-28
12  Female  Math3_Exam_Mark     2010-01-31
13  Female  Math3_Exam_Mark     2010-02-28
14  Female  Math6_Exam_Mark     2010-01-31
15  Female  Math6_Exam_Mark     2010-02-28
16  Female  Math9_Exam_Mark     2010-01-31
17  Female  Math9_Exam_Mark     2010-02-28
18  Female   ELA3_Exam_Mark     2010-01-31
19  Female   ELA3_Exam_Mark     2010-02-28
20  Female   ELA6_Exam_Mark     2010-01-31
21  Female   ELA6_Exam_Mark     2010-02-28
22  Female   ELA9_Exam_Mark     2010-01-31
23  Female   ELA9_Exam_Mark     2010-02-28
```